# Design for typeclass representing "species" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The following simplified datatype is the base of all the objects of a game:

```
data Object = Object { logic :: Logic, picture :: Picture }
data Logic = Logic { geometry :: Geometry, someAttributes :: SomeAttributes }
data Geometry = Geometry { coords :: Point, size :: Point }
data SomeAttributes = SomeAttributes { life :: Int, hasGravity :: Bool }
```

The objects are created by functions:

```
hero position = Object
    (Logic
        (Geometry position (Point 25 55))
        (SomeAttributes 100 True))
    PictureConstructor1

enemy position = Object
    (Logic
        (Geometry position (Point 25 25))
        (SomeAttributes 3 True))
    PictureConstructor2

bullet position = Object
    (Logic
        (Geometry position (Point 5 5))
        (SomeAttributes 0 False))
    PictureConstructor3

--etc. for blocks and everything else
```

Example of game structure:

```
[hero (Point 0 0), enemy (Point 50 0), enemy (Point 100 0), block (Point 0 (negate 30)), block (Point 50 (negate 30)), block (Point 100 (negate 30))]
```

Then, an `advance` function takes this list and apply gravity, collisions, ..., thus making the objets move, die, ...
This function is of type `[Object] -> [Object]`, but it doesn't change all the fields of `Object`: only `coords` and `life` are changed, while `size` and `hasGravity`, for example, always remain constant, untouched.

This constant data represents some kind of "specy attributes", or class attributes, but the "instances" carry them around, which is **not safe**, **heavy for memory** and **unpractical** for serialization.

---

I thought of making a typeclass and every instance would provide their "constants" and a constructor for fields that can change. I can't think of something better than:

```
class Object a where
    size :: Point
    baseLife :: Point
    hasGravity :: Bool
    picture :: Picture

data Hero = Hero { coords :: Point, currentLife :: Int }

instance Object Hero where
    size = Point 25 55
    baseLife = 100
    hasGravity = True
    picture = PictureConstructor1

setHero a@(Hero xy _) = Hero xy (baseLife a)
```

It's lighter and safer, but it's rather ugly because it has lost its structure (no more Logic, Geometry, ...). I think I would use lambda types if they existed :p.

Please share your ideas on how to fix these issues or alternative models you can think about.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that all these species-specific fields can be modified by other functions, but the only thing that can change during the game is, let's say, the position and the life points.

Since all data structures in haskell are immutable, I assume that when you say modify, you mean that other functions can construct new (possibly different) objects using the data constructors.

If you want to prevent that from happening, you could put the datatypes together with the functions that construct them (`hero`, `enemy` and `bullet`) into an extra module which only exports the type constructors of your datatypes together with the functions for accessing fields and the construction functions, but not the data constructors.

```
module GameData (Object, Logic, Geometry, SomeAttributes, logic, picture, geometry, someAttributes, coords, size, life, hasGravity, hero, enemy, bullet)

data Object = CreateObject { logic :: Logic, picture :: Picture }
data Logic = CreateLogic { geometry :: Geometry, someAttributes :: SomeAttributes }
data Geometry = CreateGeometry { coords :: Point, size :: Point }
data SomeAttributes = CreateSomeAttributes { life :: Int, hasGravity :: Bool }

hero position = ...
enemy position = ...
bullet position = ...
```

Then you could choose which data constructors you want to expose. Maybe it makes sense to put all the 'mutable' data into its own datatype, so you can export the data constructor of that datatype but not the data constructors of the other datatypes.

Once you have everything organized like that, you have very tight control over how your objects can be constructed, since that modules is the only thing that can do this construction, the other modules only have access to the `hero` `enemy` and `bullet` functions.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Access to fields is not the only problem; my main concern is useless creation of data. I don't want to make a new size, picture, hasGravity, etc. for each enemy/hero/... because its datatype-specific and doesn't need to be changed. To carry around fifty enemies with their entire fields (`Object (Logic (Geometry (Point x y) (Point w h)) (SomeAttributes life hasGrav)) pict` * 50 with much more fields in the real code` is less performant than `Enemy (Point x y) life` * 50 and once all the other details.

Comment: @L01man Ah, I see. Well, if you organize your data structure differently, you could just have constants like `heroTemplate`, which contain all the things that are constant for a hero and the construct the new object along the lines of `Object heroTemplate (Point x y) life`.

Comment: @L01man Also, maybe clarify your original question so that people can see that your concern is about performance. That way, people who are experts on that subject may chime in. I've heard that the haskell compiler is fairly smart about things like these, but I'm not very experienced when it comes to haskell performance, so maybe someone else can give you more insight on that.

Comment: I edited the question and hope it's better, now. I thought about separing "class static" fields and "mutable" fields but there is a hierarchy issue: coords belongs to Geometry, Life belong to SomeAttributes, and I don't want to break these types, which is what I do with a typeclass and would like to avoid.

Comment: @L01man I get what you mean. I would argue that organizing data in terms of 'species' data and 'instance' data makes a lot of sense, but I guess it's a matter of taste, and it's your design after all. In any case, I can't think of a way of keeping your structure while avoiding carrying around and/or reconstructing the 'species' data upon modification. Good luck with that.

Comment: You may be right. If I can't find any other way that's what I'll do, while keeping the old structure in comments.

Comment: @L01man: With OOP the design might be more obvious.  Haskell does not have a base OOP system, but most of the operations are available.  What operations do you need to support?

Comment: It would be some kind of static polymorphic class fields. `size (Hero (Point x y))` would return `Point 25 55` and `size (Bullet (Point x y))`: `Point 5 5`.
In C++, I believe I would write: `class Object { virtual Point getSize() const = 0; };` and `class Hero : public Object { Point getSize() const { return (Point) { 25, 55 }; } };`.